# Javascript: What Document object property can be dynamically rendered after a Web page is rendered?

Tags: javascript, dom

According to a school assignment, only one property of the Document object can be dynamically changed after a Web page is rendered.  Is it body or cookie?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manipulate the body contents, but can't assign to the body property.  It's a readonly property.  You can however set or get the cookies associated with the document. Reference: http://www.w3schools.com/htmldom/dom_obj_document.asp

Answer (score 2):

The assignment is wrong: all of the following properties have special meaning in the DOM and are writeable:

- alinkColor
- bgColor
- cookie
- fgColor
- linkColor
- title
- vlinkColor

The list above should work across different browsers. There are others (like `charset` and `defaultCharset` for IE, or [some of these](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document#Properties) for Geckos) which don't, and not all of them are [standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-1006298752).

Comment: Document Object Properties are as follows: body, cookie, domain, lastModified, referrer, title and url.

Comment: @Clark: who decided that: `lastModified` is non-standard as well, so why do you exclude other non-standard properties with cross-browser support?

Comment: @Clark: the `color` properties are even standard, just deprecated

Answer (score 0):

I think your assignment is based on out-of-date technology.

with Javascript, you can do anything after the webpage is rendered. e.g. changing the id name, properties, eventHandler, etc of any DOM dynamically.